# setDefault for Nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I use setdefault in python for nested dictionary structures.
eg..

```
self.table[field] = 0
self.table[date] = []
self.table[value] = {}
```

I would like to setdefault for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `self.table` is a dict, you could use

```
self.table.setdefault(field,0)
```

The rest are all similar. Note that if `self.table` already has a key `field`, then the value associated with that key is returned. Only if there is no key `field` is `self.table[field]` set to 0.

**Edit:** Perhaps this is closer to what you want:

```
import collections
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.CompleteAnalysis=collections.defaultdict(
            lambda: collections.defaultdict(list))

    def getFilledFields(self,sentence):
        field, field_value, field_date = sentence.split('|')
        field_value = field_value.strip('\n')
        field_date = field_date.strip('\n')
        self.CompleteAnalysis[field]['date'].append(field_date)
        self.CompleteAnalysis[field]['value'].append(field_value) 

foo=Foo()
foo.getFilledFields('A|1|2000-1-1')
foo.getFilledFields('A|2|2000-1-2')
print(foo.CompleteAnalysis['A']['date'])
# ['2000-1-1', '2000-1-2']

print(foo.CompleteAnalysis['A']['value'])
# ['1', '2']
```

Instead of keeping track of the count, perhaps just take the length of the list:

```
print(len(foo.CompleteAnalysis['A']['value']))
# 2
```

Comment: thanks one more query, how can I set self.table[tablename][field][count] = 0

Comment: TRying something like this, however not working. :-((
    def getFilledFields(self,sentence):
        count = 0
        date = []
        value = []
        field = sentence.split('|')[0]
        field_value = sentence.split('|')[1].strip('\n')
        field_date = sentence.split('|')[2].strip('\n')
        try:
            self.CompleteAnalysis[field][count] = self.CompleteAnalysis[field][count] + 1
        except:
            self.CompleteAnalysis[field][count] = 0
        self.CompleteAnalysis[field][date].append(field_date)
        self.CompleteAnalysis[field][value].append(field_value)

Comment: Could you add to your question what a sample sentence looks like and what you want self.CompleteAnalysis to look like after a call to `self.getFilledFields(sentence)`? I have a guess but am not quite sure.